# How to handle multiple AWS accounts in Kops?

Tags: amazon-web-services, kubernetes, kops

Can I pass AWS creds to Kops CLI or programmatically? How to handle multiple AWS accounts?

Comment: In case someone else stumbles on this... In addition to doing a `source` on different files with the right `KOPS_STATE_STORE` variable. To switch from one AWS profile/IAM role to another, I'd strongly recommend looking into awsume. Makes the process much simpler. And works perfectly for kops. https://github.com/trek10inc/awsume

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can redefine the `KOPS_STATE_STORE` environment variable to point to different s3 buckets in different aws accounts. You'll also have to export `AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID` and `AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY` variables for the given s3 bucket's account authorization.

To make the switch easier on yourself, do the following. Create two export var files, let's call them `aws_cluster_acct_1.env` and `aws_cluster_acct_2.env`.

aws_cluster_acct_1.env:

> export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=foo1
>
> export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=bar1
>
> export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://aws-account-kops-bucket-1

aws_cluster_acct_2.env:

> export AWS_ACCESS_KEY_ID=foo2
>
> export AWS_SECRET_ACCESS_KEY=bar2
>
> export KOPS_STATE_STORE=s3://aws-account-kops-bucket-2

Now when you want to switch between KOPS clusters in different AWS accounts, you can run either `source aws_cluster_acct_1.env` or `source aws_cluster_acct_2.env` and that will load up the appropriate environment variables for you to start doing stuff with either AWS account's KOPS clusters.

Comment: A couple of questions on this. 1. Just the S3 bucket is able to hold the entire info of the cluster (specs, creds, etc.)? 2. That will have to mean that the S3 buckets be public no?

Comment: 1. The s3 bucket holds your kops cluster configurations, master cluster admin credentials, and other cluster spec info,  but not pod specs or any k8s object. That’s the job of the etcd backend. 2. Absolutely not. Those buckets should be private and authorized access should be provided by an IAM role created in your KOPS deployment and attached to your k8s nodes. This is done more or less automatically when you deploy k8s with kops

Comment: So basically I will have to manage AWS accounts per shell right? I mean set one set of creds in one shell and another in a different set and then use them accordingly right?

Comment: You don't necessarily even need new shells, per se. I've updated my answer to provide a little more clarity on how to manage transitioning between accounts. LMK if that helps.

Comment: Just one last question. Can I create a service, deployment, etc. using `kubectl` with same names but with different AWS creds/accounts? Will `kubectl` throw any error?

Comment: is it possible to have same approach with EKS ?